# How to set maximum sentence length in spacy?

Tags: nlp, spacy

I have a string I converted to a spacy `Doc`. However, when I iterate through the `Doc.sents` object, I get sentences I found they are too long.

Is there a way when doing `doc = nlp(string)` to set the maximum length for a single sentence?

Thanks a lot, this would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this.

In normal language, while practically sentences don't get too long, there's no strict limit on the length of a sentence. Imagine a list of all fruits or something.

Partly because of that, it's not clear what to do with overlong sentences. Do you split them into segments of the max length or less? Do you throw them out entirely, or cut off words after the first chunk? The right approach depends on your application.

It should typically be easy to implement the strategy you want on top of the `.sents` iterator.

---

To split sentences into a max length or less you can do this:

```
def my_sents(doc, max_len):
    for sent in doc.sents:
        if len(sent) < max_len:
            yield sent
            continue

        # this is a long one
        offset = 0
        while offset < len(sent):
            yield sent[offset:offset+max_len]
            offset += max_len
```

However, note that for many applications this isn't useful. If you have a max length for sentences you should really think about why you have it and adjust your approach based on that.

Comment: In my use case, I would _split them into segments of the max length or less_. How would you do that?

Comment: I'm limited in terms of CUDA memory. If I feed the PyTorch model with too long sequences, I get a RuntimeError CUDA out of memory. Do you know a workaround for that?

Comment: OK, that explains things. I have no idea how you're integrating your PyTorch model with spaCy, but either do the thing above or look at spaCy's span getters. Maybe you should open another question that directly asks the problem you're trying to solve and details your network architecture? https://spacy.io/api/transformer#span_getters